# Do you know any good examples of mode-driven GUI frameworks?

Tags: design-patterns

I strongly believe UI usability and consistency would benefit a lot from frameworks able to generate high-quality GUI skeletons starting from formal specifications of data and processing requirements.

Think about the "scaffolding" concept of Ruby on Rails for basic CRUD operations pushed further. A few years ago in a project for a policy administration system we created a concept of "GUI scenario" covering things like:

Intra-page behaviours:

- master-slave field selections
- help access
- key shortcuts (for field or actions tagged "important")
- ...

Multi-step interactions:

- *search flow*: search criteria --> results --> detail
- *add new item* flow: multi-step wizard with commmit / abandon logic
- *edit item* flow
- ...

Even though the framework was lacking generality it was extremely successfull in enforcing (low-cost) a consistent GUI adhering to the project standard.

Do you know any good examples of such implementations worthwhile looking at?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, it sounds like your asking for code, or at least architecture frameworks, which generally doesn't belong here.

We've used what is now Sencha's [Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/examples/) framework for a few products now and appreciate the pre-built components and UI elements for common-action roughing.

Haven't read it, but [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel2/1011/8011/00342815.pdf?arnumber=342815&authDecision=-203) purports to discuss GUI scenarios.

In the end, I think any CMS should provide a meaningful case study in common action skeletons, like [Drupal](http://drupal.org) or [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.com).

If by "data and processing requirements" you mean to the detailed level of object and software modeling, your interface (and program, frankly) can be written in UML and generate a program. I can't attest to the usability of any of these generators.

If you're asking about a program into which you put requirements ("User can save the page," or "page opens a pop-up") and are given front-end code, on that I really haven't the foggiest. Kinda the "people" part of software design.